# Instansiating a class with protected constructor

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String str[]){
        Info i=new Info();
        i.value=20;
        System.out.println("Integer value is :"+i.value);
    }
}
class Info {
    int value;
    protected Info(){
    System.out.println("Class with protected constructor");
    }
}
```

-->I am missing something about protected modifier but could not figure it out. 
-->Till now i have read that a class with protected constructor can only be instantiated by its Sub-Classes and that too in a same package or in a different package. Then how come the above is giving me this output : Class with protected constructor
         Integer value is :20

Comment: Your `Info` class and `MyTest` reside in same package. And `protected` modifier has package visibilty. Try moving `Info` to different package, to get the error for same statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Protected` members are accessible from within `Class`, `Same package` and in `Subclass`. It doesn't have access to the `World` (other than mentioned above)

See the below table

The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

```
Access Levels
Modifier      Class    Package     Subclass         World
public          Y         Y            Y              Y
protected       Y         Y            Y              N
no modifier     Y         Y            N              N
private         Y         N            N              N
```

Comment: Than you, i was missing the point that both are inside the same package

Answer (score 4):

Because, both classes, `MyTest` and `Info` are in same package.

Classes in the same package can access the protected members without any problems

> If the member or constructor is declared protected, then  access is
>   permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
> - Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package     containing the class in which the protected member or constructor is
>     declared.

Check [JLS 6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

Answer (score 0):

What will you help in the long run is to know that ANYTHING protected can only be accessed and manipulated by its sub-classes. This includes methods, variables, etc. Classes located in the same package as a class with a protected constructor are still "aware" of the variables located within the constructor. Therefore, you are receiving your output "Class with protected constructor Integer value is :20" because the two classes are in the same package.